# Hexadecimal number to char using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hex

How do I convert, for example, the string `"C3"` to its character using JavaScript? I've tried `charCodeAt`, `toString(16)` and everything, but it doesn't work.

```
var justtesting = "C3"; // There's an input here
var tohexformat = '\x' + justtesting; // Gives the wrong hexadecimal number

var finalstring = tohexformat.toString(16);
```

Comment: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301638/javascript-convert-string-representation-of-hex-value-to-hex" related!!

Comment: You also don't have quotes around `C3`, so it's not interpreting it as a string.

Comment: yes i do. edited :)

Comment: OP is not attempting to convert decimal values to hexadecimal.

Comment: yep. it's a string.. i just can't turn a string to an hex, i.e `31` to number `1` cause when i try to add `\x` it gives me just two more chars, instead of a hex value

Comment: What is the required output for "[C3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/195_(number))"? The string "193"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All you need is [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and possibly [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

`parseInt` accepts a string and a *radix*, a.k.a the base you wish to convert from.

```js
console.log(parseInt('F', 16));
```

`String.fromCharCode` will take a character code and convert it to the matching string.

```js
console.log(String.fromCharCode(65));
```

So here's how you can convert `C3` into a number and, optionally, into a character.

```js
var input = 'C3';
var decimalValue = parseInt(input, 16); // Base 16 or hexadecimal
var character = String.fromCharCode(decimalValue);
console.log('Input:', input);
console.log('Decimal value:', decimalValue);
console.log('Character representation:', character);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is to print "&#" + CharCode like this:

```
for(var i=9984; i<=10175; i++){
    document.write(i + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + i.toString(16) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#" + i + "<br>");
}
```

OR

```
for(var i=0x2700; i<=0x27BF; i++){
    document.write(i + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + i.toString(16) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#" + i + "<br>");
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qpaycm/7qa8jsou/)

Comment: Is this a bogus answer? What are the magic numbers 9984 and 10175? What is the intent?

Comment: @PeterMortensen `magic numbers` are just a decimal representation of utf-8 character. The intent to demostrate a simple example how to turn a hexadecimal/decimal number into a char using javascript.