# Extendscript: Concatenating an Unicode value doesn't work

Tags: regex, concatenation, adobe-indesign, extendscript

Within an Extendscript Regex search in an InDesign document, it seems that I can't use the "+" operator to concatenate the "\u" and and 4-digit Unicode value. Example:

```js
var text = abcabcabc;
var re = new RegExp("\u0061", "g");
text = text.replace(re, "X");
```

will bring `XbcXbcXbc` as expected, but

```js
var text = abcabcabc;
var u = "0061";
var re = new RegExp("\u" + u, "g");
text = text.replace(re, "X");
```

will bring `\u0061bc\u0061bc\u0061bc`.

So what's wrong here? Is it the `+` operator that doesn't work at this point? Is there any other possibility to concatenate the two components so that they are recognized as a complete Unicode value? Any advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash: `"\\u" + u`.

Comment: That actually brings \u0061bc... as well. The crazy thing is that the concatenation works well in the search string but not in the replace string.

Comment: Sounds like you used this in a normal string. I thought you want a `RegExp`? If it's a real character you want, use `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a, 16))` or `String.fromCharCode('0x' + a)`(I'm not sure if this is ECMAScript3 compliant/available in ExtendScript though).

Comment: Both solutions work well ... thanks a lot!

Comment: Just for completeness, this is a duplicate of [Hex Number to Char using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40977000). To 3000+-rep users: Please vote to close. To other users: Always flag as duplicate instead of answering a dup.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer has been contributed by InSync:
To be version- and OS-independant you'd use

```
String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a, 16));
```

or

```
String.fromCharCode('0x' + a);
```

to concatenate the replace string for a RegExp operation using Adobe InDesign scripting (ExtendScript).

Answer (score 0):

The solution from the first comment works just fine for me (InDesign CC 2023, macOS):

```
var text = 'abcabcabc';
var u = '0061';
var re = new RegExp( "\\u" + u, "g");
text = text.replace(re, "X");

$.writeln(text);
alert(text);
```

Result:

```
XbcXbcXbc
```

[image]

**Update**

I just tired it on Win7 InDesign CS6 and it works fine as well:

[image]

Comment: You are abviously on MAC; I'm working on Windows. Very interesting to see the difference - after all, there seem to be slight differences. Thanks a lot for trying!

Comment: I just tired it on Win7 InDesign CS6 and it works fine as well

Comment: Again a difference - 32bit InDesign (CS6) vs. 64bit InDesign (CC2023) where some things in fact seem to work different (not only this one). Anyway - problem solved which is great.